# Material Design Fragment Transitions - Elevation and Expansion

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-transitions

I am wanting to implement the "Elevation and Expansion" transition defined in Google's Material Design Catalog (found here: https://material.google.com/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#navigational-transitions-parent-to-child) for parent-child transitions.

However, most of the posts and implementations I have found explain how to do this for Activity transitions, which is a bit different from Fragment transitions (which require a custom animation).  Has anybody had luck implementing this animation for fragment transitions?